# Wamp, External IP, Forbidden

Tags: wamp

When I am trying to access my server through my IP adress/localhost/127.0.0.1 all of thoes are working fine but when I am trying my external IP I get:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

I was looking for guide referring to the external but I only found to the localhost, If any one know some guide about fixing this problem referring to the external IP I will be very thankful.

Edit:
I found 1 guide until now referring to the firewall, The firewall is not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using apache? If so, check the config files for your server.

On one of my sites, I require a login unless the ip is 127.0.0.1; This lets me run a pdf generator service on output of certain pages. From your description, it seems your website is acting as though it is denying everything except from localhost.

Check the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/YOURSITE` file, and look at your `VirtualHost` settings.

Comment: How did you solve it? Feel free to add a new answer to your question so others can figure it out too.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried many fixes from the internet for httpd.conf, but none of them worked.

Today I had an idea and simply commented out the line `require local` in ./conf/extra/httpd-vhost.conf and...

It worked!